# Is it possible to add values that comes before a specific value in a php while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of fruit items and amount for each from a database, these items are in a particular order, I want to find the total of items sold at the moment including previous items bought.

These are the fruits and amount sold at

```
  FruitID       FruitSoldAmount
    1                 80
    2                 100
    3                 200
    4                 400
    5                 70
```

Now If I want to find total amount of fruit for each row, I will sum the previous total to the current. I expecting to do this with a php while loop, I would like to know if it is possible to this using php while loop or better still any Idea on this will help me.

```
  FruitID       FruitTotal
    1                 80 + 0
    2                 100 + 80
    3                 200 + 100 + 80
    4                 400 + 200 + 100 + 80
    5                 70 + 400 + 200 + 100 + 80
```

Thanks for helping

**UPDATE**

This is what I am playing around buh not finding my way through

```
    $total = 0;
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($searchResults)){

        $FruitID = $rows[0]['FruitID'];

    }

     foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
          if ( $row['FruitID'] != $FruitID ) {
              $total = 0;
              $FruitID = $row['FruitID'];
          }
        $total += $row['FruitSoldAmount'];
        $result[] = $row;
   }
```

Comment: In `3` where does the second 100 come from?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please share whatever you've tried so far. By the way, is the column `FruitSoldAmount` in this format, `quantity * price_per_item`?

Comment: @chris85 Please I have edited, thanks

Comment: @RajdeepPaul No it doesn't multiply to the quantity, it is just it is

Comment: @Devon With respect to which row??

Comment: Nevermind, the edit didn't load for me until now.

Comment: Okay, whats you current PHP? You should be able to use `+=`... or `.=` if you want to actually display it as an arithmetic string.

Comment: @chris85 I am currently using PHP version: 5.5.27. Is that what you requested

Comment: Your PHP code, where you have your `while` loop and you are trying to do the addition. Add that to the question.

Comment: @chris85 I have updated my question, that is how I am beating around it buh doesn't seem to work

Comment: why don't do it in mysql side ? `select sum(FruitSoldAmount) as fruitTotal from fruit`

Comment: Why the `foreach` loop? Do it all in the `while`. You also could just use the SQL approach above, unless you actually want it outputted as the equation.

Comment: Using foreach was wat I was trying with, but I actually want it outputted as the equation

Answer (score 0):

**IN MYSQL**

```
SELECT yt2.FruitID, yt2.FruitSoldAmount, (SELECT SUM(yt1.FruitSoldAmount) FROM <your_table> AS yt1 WHERE yt1.FruitID <= yt2.FruitID) AS your_sum FROM <your_table> AS yt2 ORDER BY yt2.FruitId ASC
```

IN PHP

```
    $searchResults = mysqli_query( $conn, "SELECT FruitId, FruitSoldAmount FROM <your_table> ORDER BY FruitId ASC");
    $allRows = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($searchResults)){
        $allRows[] = $row;
    }
    if(!empty($allRows))
    {
       $total = 0;
       for ( $x = 0, $l = count( $allRows); $x < $l;  $x++ ) 
       {
          $total += $allRows[$x]['FruitSoldAmount'];
          $allRows[$x]['FruitTotal'] = $total;
       }
   }
   echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($allRows);
```

ORDER BY is important for this query.